# Can't edit: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello after creating a Product i can't edit it. The form a little complex so its made it i hard to get the edit to work.

Error when i try to edit.

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass):
    17:
    18:             <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a image", :product_images, :data => { :product_image => "#product_images" } %></p>
    19:
    20:             <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, include_blank: true, prompt: "Select One Category" %>
    21:
    22:             <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    23:               <div class='sizes_container' id
```

Here is the Product form.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "custom" %>
<div class="container">
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= simple_nested_form_for @product do |f| %>

            <%= f.fields_for :product_images do |product_image| %>
              <% if product_image.object.new_record? %>
                <%= product_image.file_field(:product_image) %>
                <%= product_image.link_to_remove "Remove Image", data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this image?" } %>
              <% else %>
                <%= product_image.hidden_field :_destroy %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>

            <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a image", :product_images, :data => { :product_image => "#product_images" } %></p>

            <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, include_blank: true, prompt: "Select One Category" %>

            <% @categories.each do |category| %>
              <div class='sizes_container' id ='sizes_container_for_<%= category.id %>'>
                <% category.sizes.each do |size| %>
                  <%= label_tag size.title %>
                  <%= f.simple_fields_for :product_sizes do |product_size| %>
                    <%= product_size.input :quantity %>
                    <%= product_size.hidden_field :size_id %>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            <% end %>

            <%= f.input :title, label:"Title"%>
            <%= f.input :price, label:"Price"%>
            <%= f.input :description,label:"Description" %>
            <%= f.input :size_description, label:"Size Details"%>
            <%= f.input :shipping_description, label:"Shipping Details"%>
            <%= f.input :tag_list,label:"Tags - Seperate tags using comma ','. 5 tags allowed per product" %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Create new product", class: "btn-lg btn-success" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? I had a look around the net i couldn't find the answer. So any help would be great. Thank you in advance.

Products controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:edit, :show, :update]
  before_action :correct_user_edit, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @categories = Category.preload(:sizes).order(:name)
    @product.product_images.build
    @product.product_sizes.build
  end

  def home
    @products = Product.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def show
  end

  def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
       redirect_to @product
       flash[:success] = 'Item was successfully updated.'
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new product_params
    @product.user_id = current_user.id
    if @product.save
      redirect_to @product
      flash[:success] = "You have created a new product"
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Your product didn't save"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Product deleted"
    redirect_to user_products_path
  end

  def add_outfit_products
    @products = current_user.products
  end

  def add_outfit_similar_products
    @products = current_user.products
  end

  private

  def create_product_images
    params["product"]["product_images_attributes"].each do |index, image|
      ProductImage.create(product_image: image, product_id: @form.product.id)
    end
  end

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def product_params
     params.require(:product).permit(
      :title,
      :price,
      :description,
      :tag_list,
      :category_id,
      :size_description,
      :shipping_description,
      product_images_attributes: [:product_image, :_destroy],
      product_sizes_attributes: [:size_id, :quantity]
    )
  end

  def correct_user_edit
    if @product = current_user.products.find_by(id: params[:id])
    else
      redirect_to root_url if @product.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have `@categories` in your edit action?

Comment: @PardeepDhingra i added my products controller

Comment: You are missing `@cateogries` in edit action. add this in edit action `@categories = Category.preload(:sizes).order(:name)`

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your `@categories = nil`, but should be `@categories = []` array.
Check your Controller - Action edit, do you define `@categories`?

Comment: O yeah day. I have added my products controller.